# iam installing swift using below link and i get this error Unauthorized

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I am using a tutorial: http://swift.openstack.org/development_saio.html

I'm currently trying to create a swift environment for some test, but got the following error when getting an X-Storage-Url and X-Auth-Token using test command.

> ## Unauthorized
>
> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested.

I am new for openstack, Ples help me..

Comment: As error log says you don`t have sufficient permission to access the document. Try to send request with an authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing `memcache` in the server.

In Openstack swift Auth tokens are stored in memcache. So if memcache is not installed auth tokens are not stored which results in failure of authorization.

Comment: How does this answer the question? (From Low Quality Posts review queue, I don't know too much about this issue myself.)